# How to grab a list of items from a chunk of html code in Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab a list of syllables from the "data-syllable" part of the span tag from dictionary.com (shown below). When I try to do this with my code, it gives me a list filled with none([None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]) and I have no idea how to fix it. Please help.

Here is the tag where I want to grab data-syllable from

```
[span class="dbox-bold">prob</span>, <span class="dbox-bold" data-
syllable="im·prob·a·bly, ">improbably, </span>, <span 
class="dbox-bold" data-syllable="im·prob·a·ble·ness, ">improbableness, 
</span>, <span class="dbox-bold" data-syllable="su·per·im·prob·a·ble, 
">superimprobable, </span>, <span class="dbox-bold" data-
syllable="su·per·im·prob·a·ble·ness, ">superimprobableness, </span>, 
<span class="dbox-bold" data-syllable="su·per·im·prob·a·bly, 
">superimprobably, </span>, <span class="dbox-bold">improbable</span>, 
<span class="dbox-bold" data-syllable="imˌprobaˈbility, 
">improbability, </span>, <span class="dbox-bold" data-syllable="im
ˈprobableness, ">improbableness, </span>, <span class="dbox-bold" data-
 syllable="imˈprobably, ">improbably, </span>]
```

========================================================================

Here is my code:

```
    a = [item for item in soup.find_all('span','dbox-bold')]
    find = [item.find(name='data-syllable') for item in a]
    return find

print(count_syllables('improbable'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `name` attribute. To find `data-syllable` attribute, you need to look in `attrs` key of every item.

`find = [item.attrs.get('data-syllable', None) for item in a]`

You can see the values in the `find` now.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But when I try to return find, it still gives me the list of Nones

Comment: I've ran into a problem when I return find, it still gives me None for some of the values in the list. Do you have any idea why that could be? For example, I ran the word invisibility and it gives me [None, None, 'in·vis·i·bil·i·ty, ', 'in·vis·i·ble·ness, ', 'in·vis·i·bly, ', 'qua·si-in·vis·i·ble, ', 'qua·si-in·vis·i·bly, ', None, None, None, 'inˌvisiˈbility, ', 'inˈvisibleness, ', 'inˈvisibly, '], instead of the full list

Comment: There are many 'span' elements with class `dbox-bold` but no `data-syllable` attribute.

Comment: Is there a way for me to get the data-syllable from span without all the None values in my list output when I remove dbox-bold? Right now, I have           
        a = [item for item in soup.find_all('span')]
        span = [item.attrs.get('data-syllable') for item in a]
        return span

Comment: You can get all 'span' elements, like you have in `a`. Finally, check one by one for each span tag, if there exists `data-syllable` attribute in it. Ex : `find = [item for item in a if item.has_attr('data-syllable')]`